# how to delete object in a constructor in PHP?

Tags: php, constructor

I have my code here and I dont know how to delete object with this kind of method
$patient->deletePatient(2) im a beginner and I cant find an answer in internet and I think the way i use var_dump was incorrect please help im stuck
this is my code:

```
<?php
$index = 0;

class Clinic { 
    public $name;
    public $age;
    public $gender;
      
      
    function Patient($name,$age,$gender){
      $this->name = $name;
      $this->age = $age;
      $this->gender = $gender;
      
      $id = $name;
      $id = $age;
      $id = $gender;
    }

    function assignPatient($name,$age,$gender){
        $this->Patient($name,$age,$gender);
      }
      
    function deletePatient($id=0){

        $this->Patient($id);
        var_dump((unset) $id);

    }

}


$patient = new Clinic;

$patient->assignPatient("Patrick star",18,"Male");
$patients[$index] = $patient;
$index++;
$patient->assignPatient("SpongeBob Squarepants",17,"Male");
$patients[$index] = $patient;
$index++;
$patient->assignPatient("Eugene Krab",28,"Male");
$patients[$index] = $patient;
$index++;
$patient->deletePatient(2);
foreach($patients as $patient)
    {
     
        echo $patient->name . " ";
        echo $patient->age . " ";
        echo $patient->gender . "\n"; 
      
        
      
    }
```

Comment: Your `var_dump()` doesn't really make sense, nor is it the main issue here. If you want different patients in your array, you need to create new instances of your object. Right now, you're just changing the data in the same object and your array will just contain multiple references to the same instance. Your `$id = $name; $id = $age; $id = $gender;` also makes no sense. And `$this->Patient($id);` should throw an error since that method expects three arguments. Why would you expect that to delete anything? What exactly are you expecting this to do here?

Comment: I'd recommend reading up more about classes and objects in PHP. The title is also a bit strange, specially since your class doesn't even have a constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Patient and Clinic should be separate objects. Then you can store Patient objects inside Clinic->patients array.

```
class Patient{

    private $name;
    private $age;
    private $gender;

    public function __construct($name, $age, $gender){
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->age = $age;
        $this->gender = $gender;
    }   

    public function getName(){
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getAge(){
        return $this->age;
    }

    public function getGender(){
        return $this->gender;
    }

}

class Clinic{

    private $patients = [];

    public function getPatients(){
        return $this->patients;
    }

    public function assignPatient($name, $age, $gender){
        $this->patients[] = new Patient($name, $age, $gender);
    }

    public function deletePatient($index){
        unset($this->patients[$index]);
    }

}

$clinic = new Clinic();

$clinic->assignPatient("Patrick star",18,"Male");
$clinic->assignPatient("SpongeBob Squarepants",17,"Male");
$clinic->assignPatient("Eugene Krab",28,"Male");

$clinic->deletePatient(1);

var_dump($clinic->getPatients());
```

Comment: how can I output the age in your code? thank you by the way.

Comment: Once patients are assigned you can loop over everyone like so: foreach( $clinic->getPatients() as $patient ){ echo $patient->getAge();  } or get specific patient like so echo $clinic->getPatients()[2]->getAge();

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
class Patient {
    public $name;
    public $age;
    public $gender;

    function __construct($name, $age, $gender) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->age = $age;
        $this->gender = $gender;
    }
}

class Clinic {
    private $patients = [];
    private $patientIndex = 0;

    function assignPatient($patient) {
        $this->patients[$this->patientIndex] = $patient;
        ++$this->patientIndex;

        return $this->patientIndex;
    }

    function deletePatient($id) {
        if(array_key_exists($id, $this->patients)) {
            unset($this->patients[$id]);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    function getPatients() {
        return $this->patients;
    }
}

$clinic = new Clinic();
$patient1 = new Patient("Patrick star",18,"Male");
$id1 = $clinic->assignPatient($patient1);
$patient2 = new Patient("SpongeBob Squarepants",17,"Male");
$id2 = $clinic->assignPatient($patient2);
$patient3 = new Patient("Eugene Krab",28,"Male");
$id3 = $clinic->assignPatient($patient3);
$clinic->deletePatient($id2);

foreach($clinic->getPatients() as $patient) {
    var_dump($patient);
}
```

Comment: it has an error

Comment: One closing parenthesis was missing. I've updated the code.